# Are local writes committed to firebase in the same order as they were generated

Tags: firebase

We are pushing local updates to a dataset on an IoT board using a nodejs firebase sdk on flaky internet connection. The connection is mar with lot of packet losses.

Now supppose UpdateA is pushed followed by UpdateB to firebase (using the set() operation). UpdateA fails to make it to Firebase servers due to packet losses but UpdateB makes it.

What will happen in this case? Will firebase commit UpdateB and relay to all connected clients and then when it gets UpdateA, it will do the same for it? Or will Firebase server ensure all writes are committed in the same order as they happened on the local server and relay them in the same order as well?

Note: UpdateA and UpdateB have happened on the same server

Here are more specifics:

I am using Firebase js sdk in a nodejs service on an IoT device. The device has flaky internet connection and can be powered off without warnings. Thousands of these devices will be deployed and they have to sync certain dataset (user digital wallets) between them. Because of this conditions, I am implementing a local offline persistent cache using mongodb. All the updates to the wallet are first persisted in the db and then they are pushed to firebase. Now I push all updates to wallets serially to firebase in the order they are updated. And as callbacks for set operation will fire, I will note down the updated timestamp of the last success full write operation. Now if the device shuts off and is turned on after sometime, I can continue pushing the local updates to firebase from the updated time.

However, this logic works only if firebase guarantees that order in which I do write operations is the same order they will be committed to firebase server i.e. in the same order the callbacks of the set operation will be fired as well.

Answer (score 4):

*Firebase engineer here*

See [event guarantees](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-guarantees):

> Writes from a single client will always be written to the server and broadcast out to other users in-order.

If you're using a Firebase SDK and the connection with the Firebase server is lost, the SDK will keep a local queue of write operation it still needs to send. When the connection to the server is restored, the Firebase client sends the pending write operation in the correct order.

So in your case, UpdateA will be in that queue and sent to the server when the connection is restored.

But if you have dependencies between data in your writes, consider using a transaction. That way your `set()` operation can be specified in terms of "given this value X of property Y, set it to value Z".

Comment: Does Firebase sdk send local write operations synchronously i.e. UpdateB will be relayed only after UpdateA is acknowledge by Firebase server?

Comment: The Firebase client (all of this assumes you use one of the Firebase SDKs) keeps an open connection to the server. All requests go over that same connection. Note that it'll be a lot easier to answer questions if you specify a bit more, like what your client looks like and what you're trying to accomplish. Explaining Firebase internals is interesting too, but somewhat broad (and probably off-topic) for StackOverflow.

Comment: Assuming you use an official SDK, `Writes from a single client will always be written to the server and broadcast out to other users in-order.`. See event guarantees [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-guarantees). For multiple clients, there are, and cannot be, any guarantees of ordering as it depends on the order they arrive at the server.