# Are there guarantees about the order in which data is added to Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say that from the iOS Swift client, I write document A and then document B to Firestore.

Let's also say that my security rules prevent document B from being written unless document A exists.

Is there any guarantee that B will pass its security check, or should I put the writing of B in the callback from the writing of A? This would impair my ability to use my app offline.

Comment: This answer to a related question is two years old, but I would expect is true for the current SDK also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34158361/4815718

Comment: Thanks @BobSnyder, that's helpful.